# How to test drupal_goto within init function?

Tags: unit-testing, drupal-7, drush

So have a function that does something like this:

```
function mymod_init()
{
    $ip = '123.123.123.123';
    $newPath = mymod_redirect_calculate($ip);
    if (!empty($newPath)) drupal_goto($newPath);
}
```

This completely breaks unit testing. I have tests for the "mymod_redirect_calculate", but if I add the above to my init function as shown, the tests can't run.

From what I have gathered "exit" and "drupal_goto" breaks unit testing.

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually `drupal_goto()` ends up calling `exit()`. Using `header()` should work :

```
function mymod_init() {
  $ip = '123.123.123.123';
  $newPath = mymod_redirect_calculate($ip);
  if (!empty($newPath)) {
    $url = url($newPath, array('absolute' => TRUE));
    header('Location: ' . $url, TRUE);
  }
}
```